# returns_rows attribute is not working - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to select a row by its id value from a database and I'm using the `returns_rows`attribute of `ResultProxy` class to check if a row was returned before calling `fetchone()`.

For that I've code this:

```
book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=:isbn", {"isbn": id})
if book.returns_rows is not True:
    return "Not found."
book = book.fetchone()
// ...
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=fetchall#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.returns_rows), it is supposed to return `True` if at least a row is returned. But even if the `id` value does not exist in the DB, the *if statement* is not evaluated as true.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `if var is not True:` it's better to use just `if not var:`.

Comment: I&#39;ve tried that but I changed to that because the documentation is only clear about the value of `returns_rows` when rows are returned from the DB (in this case `returns_rows`=True). But thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess there should be misreading of documentation. `returns_rows` implementation depends on underying cursor (which is as documentation says is released immediately upon construction for UPDATE statements). Underlying cursor is also released when rows are exhausted. But I am not sure this would happen _before_ you try to do fetch. Have you tried checking that `book is None` instead of `book.returns_rows is not True`?

Comment: @nutic I've tried that and it works properly. But I was wondering why this attribute was not working in my if statement. I don't know much about database yet but would I need to use a cursor "manually" to have this attribut set to True? I'm asking this because I've tried to use it with UPDATE statement but it didn't work either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In the documentation I only see this `True if this ResultProxy returns rows.` But Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the implementation returns_rows = True when db cursor is open which means you can try to fetch some data from this cursor. But there is no guarantee that there is any data to fetch unless you try to. As for your question, I wouldn't recommend touching underlying cursor manually as SQLAlchemy is supposed to encapsulate it and fetch* methods should be enough for your needs.

Comment: "According to the documentation, it is supposed to return True if at least a row is returned." is a misreading. "True if `ResultProxy` returns rows." does not mean "a SELECT will return rows, if True", but instead that the query result *might* return rows at all (for example result of CREATE TABLE will not return rows) and as such it is legal to call the fetch* methods. Why don't you ask about the UPDATE statement case that's actually not working?

Comment: I thought I understood well when I read the documentation but I actually didn't. I'm going to study more about DB so I can understand better about this attribute. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cursor.fetchone() is not None` instead:

```
book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=:isbn", {"isbn": id})
book = book.fetchone()
if book is None:
    return "Not found."
```